# Comparing Performance of int and Integer

Tags: java

**Which one is best in programming - `int` or `Integer`? Especially whenever both are doing the same task?**

I am writing an application in Java. In most of the places of primitive data types, I use `int`; and for objects, I use `Integer`. So I am confused- which one is the best in places, where we have to use objects.

According to performance, which one is best for a Java application?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Use `int` when possible, and use `Integer` when needed. Since `int` is a primitive, it will be faster. Modern JVMs know how to optimize `Integer`s using auto-boxing, but if you're writing performance critical code, `int` is the way to go.

Take a look at [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20060423040119/http://www.glenmccl.com:80/tip_016.htm) and [this](http://openwritings.net/content/public/java/performance-primitive-data-type-vs-object-data-type) article. Although you shouldn't treat them as absolute truths, they do show that objects will be slower than their primitive counterparts.

So, use `int` whenever possible (I will repeat myself: if you're writing performance critical code). If a method requires an Integer, use that instead.

If you don't care about performance and want to do everything in an object oriented fashion, use `Integer`.

Comment: Performance is not the only thing to consider. int will use less memory than Integer (roughly speaking an Integer takes twice as much memory). If you are dealing with many numbers this can make a substantial difference

Comment: The links in the answer are broken, [here's](http://openwritings.net/content/public/java/performance-primitive-data-type-vs-object-data-type) the current link to the second article. One thing to take from the article is that when considering performance, for many use-cases the difference between using int and Integer will not be key. Unless you're dealing with a very large number of Integers or calculations.

Answer (score 7):

Use `int` wherever possible. Use `Integer` only if:

- You need a way to represent "no value" or "uninitialized". `Integer` can be `null`, an `int` always has an int value.
- You want to use collections like `List` (though you can use `int` externally and have autoboxing hide the fact that the collection internally stores `Integer` instances).
- You're using an API, framework or tool that requires you to use `Integer` or `Object`, or doesn't work with primitive types.
- You need to be able to synchronize on the object (very unlikely).

Comment: Do these recommendations still hold true today? I am doing some pretty heavy JSON deserialization-related work and I'm having trouble coming up with a strategy for representing uninitialized (optional) fields. I will ask a separate question if more appropriate.

Comment: Nowadays, one would rather use `OptionalInt` and its `.empty()` for "no value".

Answer (score 3):

`int` a primitive, typically it should be faster. It just carries the raw number data.

`Integer` is an object, it carries some extra stuff so you e.g. can put the number in lists.

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative view.... perhaps you should use neither Integer nor int.

If the value is really an object with behaviour - like say an amount of money, or a distance or something, then perhaps you should be using an object with behaviour.

You can see more about this kind of thing here:

http://www.time4tea.net/wiki/display/MAIN/Microtypes

Although this may be "slower", the additional type safety will make the programming, testing and debugging of your system much easier & faster.

Answer (score 1):

int is primitive, Integer is an int wrapped up as an object.

It really depends how you are going to be using them.