# Is Integer slower than int?

Tags: java

In competitive programming I used Integer instead of int but it got me TLE error Can you tell me why? Basically i have to just sort the array and traverse it.
   my code is here

```
    class Main
    {
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
      Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
      int scene = sc.nextInt();
      int j=1;
      while(j<=scene)
      {
        int need = sc.nextInt();
        int frnds = sc.nextInt();
        int arr[] = new int[frnds];
        for(int i=0;i<frnds;i++)
            arr[i] = sc.nextInt();
        Arrays.sort(arr);
        int count =0;
        System.out.println("Scenario #"+j+":");
        for(int i=frnds-1;i>=0;i--)
        {
            count++;
            need -= arr[i];
            if(need<=0) {
                System.out.println(count);
                break;
            }
        }
        if(need>0)
            System.out.println("impossible");
        System.out.println();
        j++;
    }
   }
  }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4624933/comparing-performance-of-int-and-integer

Comment: yeah thank u So basically if we compare normal operations like traversing then int will be faster than Integer. Am i right?

Comment: It is somewhat, but that's almost never the core problem.

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21797573/why-is-scanner-slower-than-bufferedreader-when-reading-from-input and https://www.quora.com/Why-is-Scanner-so-much-slower-than-BufferedReader as well.

Comment: I understand what you guys are trying to say that buffered reader is faster than Scanner.But in above given code I used Scanner but I submit two versions one with storing values in Integer array and one with int array .The code in which i used Integer gave me TLE. I wanted to know reason behind that and I think the above guys had given somewhat right answer that wrapper classes are slower than primitive data types. If I am wrong then please correct me.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In your example, you are using `Scanner` to read data from the input stream but its extremely slow, use `BufferedReader` instead.
**Example**:

```
try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in))) {
     String line = reader.readLine();
     ....
} catch (IOException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
}
```

That will speed up your execution time.

Comment: @J_V I am unable to see how this answers the question you asked. The assertion that `Scanner` is 'extremely slow' is false, and the apparent assertion that this will speed up your code more than using `int` instead of `Integer` ditto.